# Link visible only for particular user (by id or email) AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a link :

```
<li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#postModal">Add prediction</a></li>
```

For now it's visible for all signed in users, but I want to make it visible only for me (by user.id, which is 989fc9a9-cc63-4c28-b308-6360b779d105, or user.email, which is nikitaribakovs96@gmail.com).

I tried : `ng-show="signedIn() && $scope.user.email == 'nikitaribakovs96@gmail.com'"`, but this didn't work :(

Here is a source code for auth service :
https://github.com/NiR-IT/tennispredictions/blob/master/scripts/services/Auth.js

My app:
https://sportpredictions.firebaseapp.com/#/

I would very appreciate, if some could help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that you don't need `$scope` in that `ng-show`.

```
ng-show="signedIn() && currentUser.email == 'nikitaribakovs96@gmail.com'"
```

Comment: with user.email ==... button does't shows at all :(

Comment: Sounds like it's doing what you want then :)  I dug into the other code in your github repository and it looks like the `NavController` is setting `$scope.currentUser`, not `$scope.user`. So you would need to either change the `ng-show` to reference `currentUser` or update `NavController` to set `$scope.user` instead.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I've fixed it yesterday. But still thank you very much for your help ;)